# Magento2: How to get custom comment for order in REST API?

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I ve installed Infobeans OSComments. Module adds additional field on checkout page and save value to Order Page. Is it possible to have access to this comment via REST API ? Can this value cand be add to all data avaible when I use:
{{magento_url}}/rest/V1/orders/:id ?

```
<?php
```

/**

*/

namespace Infobeans\OSComments\Plugin\Checkout\Model;

class ShippingInformationManagement
{
// @codingStandardsIgnoreLine
protected $quoteRepository;

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $quoteRepository
) {
    $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
}

/**
 * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject
 * @param $cartId
 * @param \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
 */
// @codingStandardsIgnoreLine
public function beforeSaveAddressInformation(
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject,
    $cartId,
    \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
) {
    $extAttributes = $addressInformation->getExtensionAttributes();
    $deliveryComment = htmlspecialchars($extAttributes->getDeliveryComment());
    $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);
    $quote->setDeliveryComment($deliveryComment);
}
```

}

Is there easy way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this. Here is a way to do this. In my example i did it with order repository but it should be similar with the quote repository just change order by quote everywhere in the code.

Create the file  NameSpace/ModuleName/etc/webapi_rest/di.xml . If you use soap you can create the same file here NameSpace/ModuleName/etc/webapi_soap/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="orderInformationUpdate" type="NameSpace\ModuleName\Plugin\Api\OrderRepository" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Then create your plugin NameSpace/ModuleName/Plugin/Api/OrderRepository.php .In my case i had to add 3 attributes to the orders fetched by the api and also add them when retrieving a list of order too.

```
<?php

namespace NameSpace\ModuleName\Plugin\Api;

use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderExtensionFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemExtensionFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderSearchResultInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;


class OrderRepository
{


    /**
     * Order Extension Attributes Factory
     *
     * @var OrderExtensionFactory
     */
    protected $extensionFactory;

    /**
     * OrderRepository constructor.
     * @param OrderExtensionFactory $extensionFactory
     * @param OrderItemExtensionFactory $itemExtensionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        OrderExtensionFactory $extensionFactory,
        OrderItemExtensionFactory $itemExtensionFactory
    )
    {
        $this->extensionFactory = $extensionFactory;
        $this->itemExtensionFactory = $itemExtensionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Add "delivery_type" extension attribute to order data object to make it accessible in API data
     *
     * @param OrderRepositoryInterface $subject
     * @param OrderInterface $order
     *
     * @return OrderInterface
     */
    public function afterGet(OrderRepositoryInterface $subject, OrderInterface $order)
    {
        $taxAreaCode = $order->getData('tax_area_code')??"";
        $navVatRegistrationNo = $order->getData('nav_vat_registration_no')??"";
        $navTaxExemptionNo = $order->getData('nav_tax_exemption_no')??"";

        $extensionAttributes = $order->getExtensionAttributes();
        $extensionAttributes = $extensionAttributes ? $extensionAttributes : $this->extensionFactory->create();
        $extensionAttributes->setTaxAreaCode($taxAreaCode);
        $extensionAttributes->setNavVatRegistrationNo($navVatRegistrationNo);
        $extensionAttributes->setNavTaxExemptionNo($navTaxExemptionNo);
        $order->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);

        return $order;
    }

    /**
     * Add "delivery_type" extension attribute to order data object to make it accessible in API data
     *
     * @param OrderRepositoryInterface $subject
     * @param OrderSearchResultInterface $searchResult
     *
     * @return OrderSearchResultInterface
     */
    public function afterGetList(OrderRepositoryInterface $subject, OrderSearchResultInterface $searchResult)
    {
        $orders = $searchResult->getItems();

        foreach ($orders as &$order) {
            $taxAreaCode = $order->getData('tax_area_code')??"";
            $navVatRegistrationNo = $order->getData('nav_vat_registration_no')??"";
            $navTaxExemptionNo = $order->getData('nav_tax_exemption_no')??"";

            $extensionAttributes = $order->getExtensionAttributes();
            $extensionAttributes = $extensionAttributes ? $extensionAttributes : $this->extensionFactory->create();
            $extensionAttributes->setTaxAreaCode($taxAreaCode);
            $extensionAttributes->setNavVatRegistrationNo($navVatRegistrationNo);
            $extensionAttributes->setNavTaxExemptionNo($navTaxExemptionNo);
            $order->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);

        }

        return $searchResult;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added to event.xml code

```
<event name="sales_order_load_after">
        <observer name="sales_order_load_tip_and_trick_attribute" instance="Infobeans\OSComments\Observer\Sales\OrderLoadAfter" />
</event>
```

OrderLoadAfter.php

```
<?php

namespace Infobeans\OSComments\Observer\Sales;



use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;



class OrderLoadAfter implements ObserverInterface

{

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)

{

$order = $observer->getOrder();

$extensionAttributes = $order->getExtensionAttributes();



if ($extensionAttributes === null) {

$extensionAttributes = $this->getOrderExtensionDependency();

}

$attr = $order->getData('delivery_comment');

$extensionAttributes->setDeliveryComment($attr);

$order->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);

}



private function getOrderExtensionDependency()

{

$orderExtension = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(

'\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderExtension'

);

return $orderExtension;

}

}
```

And works fine. Thank you for reply.